# JS cloneNode() with a new element - createElement()

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I'm trying to clone an element into a brand new element, but I need to check that the parent exists first, so I need my clones to live inside of an `if` statement.

How can I define my nodes/elements first so I can use them after?

This was my best attempt so far:

```
let title = document.createElement("h2");
if ( ... ) {
    title = document.querySelector('.title').cloneNode(true);
}
document.getElementById("details").appendChild(title);
```

When I try to do something like this, I get a TypeScript error stating that `Type 'Node' is missing the following properties from 'HTMLHeadingElement': align, accessKey, etc`

I feel like I need to define my `title` differently, but I'm not sure how or what to define it as.

Any tips/ideas?

Comment: Is that a TypeScript compile error? Also, more context (a [mre]?) could help.

Comment: Yes, it is a TypeScript error. I'll update my question to include that info.

Comment: The code I provided is where I'm seeing the error. I can't assign my cloneNode to title, because I get that error I stated. I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type 'Node' is missing the following properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72727209/type-node-is-missing-the-following-properties)

Comment: If the element with the class of `title` is a heading element, you should probably just use a type assertion. If it isn't you may need to annotate `title` as `HTMLElement` manually.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here which are combining.

In theory, `document.querySelector('.title')` could return **any** kind of Element **or** `null`. You should test to make sure it returns what you are expecting. You can do this with a custom typeguard function:

```js
const isH2 = (value: null | Element): value is HTMLHeadingElement => value?.tagName === "H2";
```

Second, TypeScript doesn't know that `somethingYouKnowIsH2.clondNode(true)` will return another H2, but you can assert it is (i.e. say that you know better than the compiler) with `as HTMLHeadingElement` or perform the test again.

```js
let title = document.createElement("h2");
let a = 1;
if ( a === 1 ) {
    const foundTitle = document.querySelector('.title');
    if (isH2(foundTitle)) {
        const clonedTitle = foundTitle.cloneNode(true);
        if (isH2(clonedTitle)) title = clonedTitle;
    }
}
```